# How to Verify People's faces Using Camera

Tags: opencv, xamarin.forms, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I have some program that I want to do face verification by previously stored people faces in app data, and use the device's camera to get the current person standing in front of it, to make the program log the user in.

I have found some code but I don't know how to use it, it uses OpenCVSharp.
Can anyone tell me how to do this verification in Xamarin Forms?

P.S:- I've found some resources that **Aren't** Free, such as EmguCV, I want something that is free.

Comment: https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Cognitive service
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/
It has a free tier(more than enough if you have less than 100 users I'd say) to use.

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't enough